# R- project Buttons and gui

Tags: r, button

This might be an "amateur" question

Firstly, I'm used to programming in java or c++, so I am realy new to R.

What I need to do is create a program that needs the statistical abilities
of R, but needs to be used by someone that knows very little about computers. 
So what im looking for is

- something like JButtons for Java, only with R.
- something to make a gui with and is simple to apply.

I've searched the web and R-books, but the only help thats out there is of statistic nature.

Any help on where to learn about gui, or a
library with written methods will be apreciated. the gui should be as simple as possible, no need for fancy or flexible codes. I need buttons on a page.

Comment: If you're familiar with Java, then use `JGR` and `Deducer` for your project.

Comment: If you search a little harder you might find a book on the topic and several papers :) Here are some other ideas besides gWidgets (though that is viable as shujaa notes): rJava allows you to program GUIs within Java (See JGR and Deducer mention by Andrie); RGtk2, qtbase, and tcltk allow you to access these toolkits from within R (many examples on CRAN); There are R <--> python channels that would let you leverage bindings for python (http://www.red-r.org/ uses this approach).

Answer (score 3):

Check out the `gWidgets` package. They've got a very nice vignette, as well as a handy little system to automagically create a (editable!) gui for a particular function.
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets/index.html